# Sum values in range if lower than a threshold otherwise sum the threshold value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As per the title, the best I could come up with is this, however it yields an error. My unremarkable knowledge of Excel prevents me from making further progress.

This example formula should add all A1 cells in worksheets WS1 through WS10 if their value is lower than 1, otherwise add 1.

```
=SUM(IF(WS1:WS10!A1<1,WS1:WS10!A1,1))
```

I'm working with Excel 2003 in Italian, I hope I translated correctly the syntax to match the English version.

Comment: That syntax works with a normal reference, e.g. a range of cells in one worksheet but you can't use "3d" references with that type of formula. Are the worksheets actually called WS1, WS2 etc?

Comment: I'm aware that my grasp of Excel syntax is subpar. :/
Unfortunately the sheets are not called like that, they are month names. The good news is that it's not so many sheets so your proposed solution still works well for me. 30-some sheets would have been cumbersome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted but here's one way to get the result you want:

`=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT("WS"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}&"!A1"),"<1"),COUNTIF(INDIRECT("WS"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}&"!A1"),">=1"))`

The SUMIF part sums all the values <1 and then the COUNTIF part gives you 1 for each value > 1